# How to get MSL coordinates during EDL from SPICE kernel?

Tags: mars, landing, entry-descent-landing, spice

Upon trying to extract MSL position above surface by decoding a SPICE kernel, I am gettin this error:

> At epoch 3.9750216818313E+08 TDB (2012 AUG 06 05:16:08.183 TDB), there
> is  insufficient information available to transform from reference
> frame -76000 (MSL_ROVER) to reference frame 1 (J2000). MSL_ROVER is a
> CK frame; a CK file  containing data for instrument or structure
> -76000 at the epoch shown above, as  well as a corresponding SCLK kernel, must be loaded in order to use this frame.

But I don't understand WHERE I mentioned MSL_ROVER in my source! I am recyclying the source for the rover, but I thought I removed any reference from it!

This is my code; I removed all the parts related to rover from the [original source](https://github.com/NASA-AMMOS/timecraftjs/blob/master/example/index.js):

```
import * as TimeCraft from '../src/index.js';
window.TimeCraft = TimeCraft;

( async function() {

    console.log("Loading...");
    const buffers = await Promise.all([
        // kernels from
        // https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/pds/data/msl-m-spice-6-v1.0/mslsp_1000/extras/mk/msl_chronos_v07.tm
        '../kernels/lsk/naif0012.tls',
        '../kernels/spk/de425s.bsp',

        '../kernels/sclk/msl_76_sclkscet_00016.tsc',
        '../kernels/sclk/msl_lmst_ops120808_v1.tsc',

        '../kernels/pck/pck00008.tpc',

        //'../kernels/spk/msl_cruise.bsp',
        '../kernels/spk/msl_edl_v01.bsp',
        //'../kernels/spk/msl_ls_ops120808_iau2000_v1.bsp',
        //'../kernels/spk/msl_atls_ops120808_v1.bsp',

        '../kernels/fk/msl_v08.tf',
    ].map( p => fetch( p ).then( res => res.arrayBuffer() ) ) );

    buffers.forEach( buffer => {

        TimeCraft.loadKernel( buffer );

    } );

    const utcEl = document.querySelector('[name="utc"]');
    const etEl = document.querySelector('[name="et"]');
    const lstEl = document.querySelector('[name="mars lst"]');
    const lmstEl = document.querySelector('[name="msl lmst"]');
    const sclkEl = document.querySelector('[name="msl sclk"]');
    const sunEl = document.querySelector('[name="msl sun direction"]');
    const MSL = document.querySelector('[name="MSL"]');
    const EDLutc = document.querySelector('[name="EDLutc"]');

    console.log("Done.");

    let EDLstartJStimeMs =  new Date("2012-AUG-06 05:15:00 00Z").getTime();
    let EDKcurrJStimeMs = EDLstartJStimeMs;

    setInterval(() => {

        //let utc = new Date().toISOString();

        EDKcurrJStimeMs += 1000;
        let utcEDL = new Date(EDKcurrJStimeMs).toISOString(); // Last: 05:19:04
console.log( utcEDL);

        //utc = utc.slice(0, utc.length - 1);
        utcEDL = utcEDL.slice(0, utcEDL.length - 1);
console.log(utcEDL);

        const etEDL = TimeCraft.Spice.utc2et(utcEDL);
console.log( etEDL);

        // See conversion code outlined in
        // https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/pds/data/msl-m-spice-6-v1.0/mslsp_1000/data/sclk/msl_76_sclkscet_00016.tsc

        //const sunPos = TimeCraft.Spice.spkpos('SUN', et, 'MSL_TOPO', 'LT+S', '-76').ptarg;
const MSLpos = TimeCraft.Spice.spkpos('-76', etEDL, 'J2000', 'LT+S', '499').ptarg;

        //sunEl.childNodes[0].textContent = `${sunDir[0].toFixed(4)}, ${sunDir[1].toFixed(4)}, ${sunDir[2].toFixed(4)}`;

MSL.childNodes[0].textContent = `${MSLpos[0].toFixed(4)}, ${MSLpos[1].toFixed(4)}, ${(MSLpos[2]-3376.2).toFixed(4)}`;
        EDLutc.childNodes[0].textContent = utcEDL;
console.log("------------------");
        // mars radius: 3376.2 km
        // Last available date for EDL: 2012-Aug-06 05:19:04.0000
        // MSL EDL kernel: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/MSL/kernels/spk/


    }, 1000);

} )();
```

The key statement is:

```
TimeCraft.Spice.spkpos('-76', etEDL, 'J2000', 'LT+S', '499').
```

...based on [Timecraft library](https://github.com/NASA-AMMOS/timecraftjs/blob/master/src/spice.js) and the [spkpos()](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/FORTRAN/spicelib/spkpos.html) function it exposes.

"-76" is MSL, not the rover, so why does the libraty complain about referring the rover?

Kernels are here:

https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/MSL/kernels/spk/

MSL EDL kernel:
https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/MSL/kernels/spk/msl_edl_v01.bsp

---

After additional testing:

This line:

const MSLpos = TimeCraft.Spice.spkpos('**MSL**', etEDL, 'IAU_MARS', 'LT+S', 'MARS').ptarg;

causes error:

At epoch 3.9750156818313E+08 TDB (2012 AUG 06 05:06:08.183 TDB), there is insufficient information available to transform from reference frame -76000 (**MSL_ROVER**) to reference frame 1 (J2000).

in cspice.js:3

This line:

const MSLpos = TimeCraft.Spice.spkpos('**MSL_SPACECRAFT**', etEDL, 'IAU_MARS', 'LT+S', '**MARS**').ptarg;

causes error:

Insufficient ephemeris data has been loaded to compute the position of -76010 (**MSL_SPACECRAFT**) relative to **0 (SOLAR SYSTEM BARYCENTER)** at the ephemeris epoch 2012 AUG 06 05:06:08.183

Kernel **msl_v08.tf** contains these data:

- MSL                      -76
- MSL_ROVER                -76000
- MSL_SPACECRAFT           -76010

Comment: This guy was able to extract full EDL data from spice kernels, but I am not able to get in touch with him... although he's active also in this site as @kwan3217 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2Ynu8sms7g

Comment: In case anybody wants to try helping, I found that version 2.0beta of Timecraft.js library ( https://github.com/NASA-AMMOS/timecraftjs ) now exposes spkpos() function from CSPICE library; this function provides position of an object w.r.t. another, given some user-specified kernels; I am working on a page to get these data for MSL ( http://win98.altervista.org/timecraftjs-2.0.0-alpha2/example/index-mio.html ) , but currently I get an error: it complains about me asking info for MSL rover rather than MSL descent stage, hence it does not work.

Comment: @kwan3217 = user:31590 ; his blog: https://stkwans.blogspot.com/search/label/MSL

Comment: NASA usually has two types of trajectories. The "predicts" and the "navigation." Predict stands for predicted trajectories, which are generated by the navigation team and are the predicted trajectory of the spacecraft. The navigation kernel (which usually only has the mission name with an ID) is the real trajectory the spacecraft has taken, and is published after the spacercaft has flown this trajectory. So you may be using that kernel instead of the predicts one, and therefore it doesn't contain any future predicted trajectory. I don't know if NAS published predicts for their missions.